# Tail-recursion with objects

Tags: c++, recursion, tail-recursion

I have a recursive function that I would like to make tail-recursive. My actual problem is more complex and context-dependent. But the issue I would like to solve is demonstrated with this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

struct obj
{
    int n;

    operator int&() { return n; }
};

int tail(obj n)
{
    return tail(obj{ n + 1 > 1000 ? n - 1000 : n + 1 });
}

int main()
{
    tail(obj{ 1 });
}
```

It seems natural that this is tail-recursive. It is not, though, because the destructor of `obj n` has to be called each time. At least MSVC13 (edit:) *and MSVC15* do not optimize this. If I replace `obj` with int and change the calls accordingly, it becomes tail-recursive as expected.

My actual question is: Is there an easy way to make this tail-recursive apart from just replacing `obj` with `int`? I am aiming for performance benefits, so playing around with heap-allocated memory and `new` is most likely not helpful.

Comment: Easiest way: get a better compiler, yours is outdated anyway...

Comment: msvc15 does not do it, either

Comment: How do you expect this tail recursion to terminate?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "the destructor of `obj n` has to be called each time"? Each `obj n` will be destructed as the stack unwinds from your recursive base case (which is currently absent). When/how do you want the destructor called?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't. A common test for tail-recursion is to check for stack overflow (the error, not this site :)) which is why I have designed it this way

Comment: @AndyG The destructor is called after the recursive call returns, which destroys the tail recursion because the last call of the function is not a recursive one to itself

Comment: Your function is actually infinitely recursive.   To be tail recursive, there would need to be an end condition, in which a call to `tail()` does not result in another call to `tail()`.   Instead, a new value is computed (using objects) and that is passed to `tail()` regardless.

Comment: @Peter This issue has been discussed in earlier comments before

Comment: The thing you're missing is that there is no "last call to the function".

Comment: I do not miss it. It does not matter

Comment: Really?  Explain how your `tail()` differs in effect from `int tail() {obj t{ n + 1 > 1000 ? n - 1000 : n + 1 }; return tail(t);}` which is infinitely recursive, with no end condition which would make it tail recursive.

Comment: @Peter You are missing the point. It is infinite, yes. But if I replace `obj` with some bare `int`, MSVC13/15 can optimize the call stack away. With `obj`, it cannot. Whether or not it is infinite does not play a role and integrating a stop condition will not help MSVC to optimize it better anyways. Also, the definition of tail-recursion that I know does not demand and end condition, why should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a temporary, I assume you don't need the object after the recursive call.

One fairly hackish solution is to allocate an object, pass a pointer to it, and reallocate it before making the recursive call, to which you pass the object you newly constructed.

```
struct obj
{
    int n;

    operator int&() { return n; }
};

int tail_impl(obj*& n)
{
    int n1 = *n + 1 > 1000 ? *n - 1000 : *n + 1;
    delete n;
    n = new obj{n1};
    return tail_impl(n);
}

int tail(obj n)
{
  obj *n1 = new obj{n};
  auto ret = tail_impl(n1);
  delete n1;
  return ret;
}

int main()
{
    tail(obj{ 1 });
}
```

I've obviously omitted some crucial exception safety details. However [GCC is able to turn `tail_impl` into a loop](https://godbolt.org/g/jVdPq8), since it is indeed tail recursion.

Comment: Great idea, indeed! However, I indeed need the object not be changed. My true story is that I have parts that ought to be tail-recursive and others that do not... Maybe, your solution can be used anyways, I would still be looking for a non-reference solution - if there is any

Comment: How does the `tail_impl` recursion end?

Comment: @0x499602D2 - It doesn't, like in the OP's post. They use the infinite recursion to test if the code is replaced by a loop. If it doesn't, a stack overflow occurs.

Comment: Since there does not seem to be a better solution, I'll mark it as solved. Tail recursion might add significant benefits and passing objects by value is no bizarre use-case, so I hope this will be improved in future C++ compilers

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:** No.

**Longer Answer:** You might find a way to achieve this but certainly no easy one.
Since tail call optimization is not required by the standard, you can never know for sure if some minor change to your program will make the compiler fail to optimize the code.

Worse, consider what happens when you need to debug your program. The compiler will almost certainly not optimize advanced tail calls with debugger flags, which means that your program will only work correctly in release mode. This will make the program much harder to maintain.

**Alternative to tail recursion**
Just write a loop. It can always be done and it is likely to be much, much less convoluted. It also doesn't use the heap, so the overhead will be much smaller.

Comment: thank you! your answer is more straight to the point, StoryTeller's is more helpful in most cases, though, which is why I gave the flag to him. I hope this is understandable

Comment: Well... the useful thing would be to write a loop instead. I completely forgot to mention that in my answer, so I have added it now. :-)

Comment: Also a good thought, thank you. Sadly, I cannot upvote once again